# How to handle Custom Boolean strings with Jackson Streaming API

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using the Streaming API of Jackson to parse JSON strings. I need to support "YES" as a boolean type.

```
JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
```

and then doing

```
JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(jsonString);
```

and then looping around the jp.nextToken() piece. Looking for the necessary starting pieces and jumping in, creating my arrays/maps as necessary.  This works great for all the usual suspects.  However, i get an exception when i hit:

```
{ "a": false, "b": Yes }
```

I need to support Yes/No as this is coming from another system.

Any advice?  I tried this http://hussainpithawala.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/overriding-default-serializationdeserialization-behaviour-of-jackson-json-serializer/ but that doesn't seem to work in this scenario.

Comment: It's really the invalid JSON {"a":false,"b":Yes} and not {"a":false,"b":"Yes"}?

Comment: the problem is the "b" key; the "a" key parses just fine.

Comment: Right.  The question I asked still stands.

Comment: I modified the original source (2 files) to allow for this.  It was only two files i needed to touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you submit a request to the Jackson project to add a JsonParser.Feature for ALLOW_UNQUOTED_VALUES.  (Issues can be submitted at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON.)  This would then allow you to process the input and provide custom deserialization.  As things are now, Jackson will throw an exception and not provide an opportunity to handle the problem, as best I can tell.